# How to set and keep language syntax type on .babelrc file

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor, babeljs

In Atom 1.18 every time I open the editor my .babelrc file defaults to the `JSON` file type, which makes syntax highlighting look way off. And I have to keep changing it back to the `Babel` type.

[image]

How to fix (temporarily):

[image]

[image]

Have to reset it every time I close and open the .babelrc file.

Now I realize this is a file that will be rarely touched, but would be helpful to know how to fix this for other file type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very specific way to set this up in the config.cson

https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-do-i-make-atom-recognize-a-file-with-extension-x-as-language-y/26539

http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#configuring-with-cson

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "source.js.jsx": [
        "js"
        "es6"
        "es"
        "babel"
        "babelrc"
        "jsx"
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I removed these errors was to just make the file JSON compatible.
Not the perfect solution but works.

```
//.babelrc
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ],
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false}],
    "react",
  ],
}
```